# XQuery - How to remove empty subelement

Tags: xquery

I have the following XQuery:

```
<a> {
    for $p in doc("p.xml")//p
    return
        <p q="{$p/@q}> {
            for $w in $p//@w
            where count(doc("r.xml")//s[@w = $w]) = 0
            return
                <s w="{$w}"></s>
        } </p>
} </a>
```

When I run galax-run, it will give the following result (After I formatted it):

```
<a>
  <p q="p1">
    <s w="S"/>
    <s w="Sc"/>
    <s w="L"/>
  </p>
  <p q="p2"/>
  <p q="p3">
    <s w="S"/>
  </p>
</a>
```

I want to delete `<p q="p2"/>` in the result because there is nothing in the element. So the result I want is:

```
 <a>
  <p q="p1">
    <s w="S"/>
    <s w="Sc"/>
    <s w="L"/>
  </p>
  <p q="p3">
    <s w="S"/>
  </p>
</a>
```

How do I modify the XQuery in order to get this result? Thank you in advance!

Comment: One more information needed: input XML that you use to get that result

Comment: it is too long to post here... sorry

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear without sample input XML, but I think, you can use `if-then-else` construct to skip `<p>` elements which `$content` would be empty. Something like this (untested) :

```
<a> {
    for $p in doc("p.xml")//p
    let $content := 
        for $w in $p//@w
        where count(doc("r.xml")//s[@w = $w]) = 0
        return $w
    return
        if($content) then 
            <p q="{$p/@q}"> {
                for $c in $content
                return
                    <s w="{$c}"></s>
            } </p>
        else ()
} </a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave me lots of inspirations. Inside <p q="{$p/@q}"> { ... } </p> I just put $content, and no if-then-else. But after let, before return, I put "where count($content) > 0". Now it works, thank you again!